# Can I edit a file in any site and update the page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I would like to know, is there a way to edit a Javascript file or a specific page, on any website, and **refresh** this page and **show my changes**?

For example, there is a website: http://example.com.
Many files are requested including a Javascript file:

http://example.com/assets/app.js

Can I modify this `app.js` file, and show my **modifications** when updating the page or is this not possible?
For example, save the file my cache? Or something like that?

and Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally speaking, you can't directly modify the files like assets/app.js, etc, since they are stored and read from the backend server of http://example.com.

However, you can still make custom changes to some specific pages/websites by scripts/styles injecting.

I think you might be interested in some browser plugins/scripts like:
Tampermonkey: https://www.tampermonkey.net/, Greasyfork: https://greasyfork.org/en, Stylish: https://userstyles.org and so on ... :)